# Accessing the system integrated social network accounts

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is it possible to detect whether the user has registered a facebook/twitter/live/linkedin account in wp7? just for enable/disable a sharelinktask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible. Basically there is only one [ShareStatusTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394027%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) (or [ShareLinkTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394009%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)) and the user is able to select from a list of social networks they are currently signed in with. There is no way however for us to know which social networks specifically they have signed into.

Answer (score 1):

As loyalpengiun mentions, it's not currently possible. The best I can advise is to vote for my uservoice feature and hope it's included in a future release:

> [Add a GrantAccountAccessTask for obtaining temporary access to social media accounts](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/2431302-add-a-grantaccountaccesstask-for-obtaining-tempora)